# $H \cong \frac{Gl_2(\mathbb{R})}{SO(2)}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to prove that the upper-half complex plane H, is isomorphic to General Linear group of order 2 (over the reals), quotationed out by the special orthogonal group.

I believe I can prove this using the first fundamental theorem of Isomorphisms, however, I am having a hard time coming up with a homomorphism that takes H to GL2(R).

Comment: What do you mean by "upper half complex plane"?

Comment: $\Bbb{H} = \{ z \in \Bbb{C},\Im(z) >0\}$ is a topological space, not a group.  The map $\pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d}. z= \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ is a group action of $GL_2$ on $\Bbb{H}$, as $ai+b=\pmatrix{a & b \\ 0 & 1}.i$ 
the action is transitive : $\{ \gamma . i,\gamma \in GL_2\} = \Bbb{H}$, and $\gamma .i = i$ iff $\gamma \in SO_2$, thus $\gamma SO_2 \mapsto \gamma . i$ is an isomorphism $GL_2 / SO_2 \to \Bbb{H}$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications.

Comment: You should prove the last assertion, which is that $\gamma.i = \alpha.i$ iff $\gamma SO_2 = \alpha SO_2$

Comment: What you are trying to prove is false. You should use the special linear group instead.

Comment: SL2(z)? How is it false for Gl2(Z)?

Comment: $SL(2, R)$ of course, not $SL(2,Z)$! As for why it is wrong think about dimensions: $GL(2,R)$ is 4-dimensional, $SO(2)$ is 1-dimensional, so the quotient is $3$-dimensional, while the upper half-plane is real 2-dimensional. Also, $GL(2,R)$ is not connected, $SO(2)$ is connected, hence $GL(2,R)/SO(2)$ is disconnected. Lastly, $SO(2)$ is not a normal subgroup, so the quotient is not a group. However, it is a topological space and the "isomorphism" in your question is a homeomorphism, not a "homomorphism". Where did you get this problem from?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I was reading a book on Modular Forms and came across the Homeomorphism.